# Swift: Initialisers for conditional binding must have Optional type,not NSURL

Tags: ios, swift

I don't know what's going wrong here.please help me

```
func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton){
    print("button pressed")


    if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("book", ofType: "pdf") {
        if let targetURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path) {

            docController = UIDocumentInteractionController(URL: targetURL)
            let url = NSURL(string:"itms-books:");

            if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(url!) {

                docController!.presentOpenInMenuFromRect(CGRectZero, inView: self.view, animated: true)

                print("iBooks is installed")

            }else{

                print("iBooks is not installed")
            }

        }
    }    }
```

and error is here

```
   if let targetURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path)
```

please tell me what is wrong here while answering.
Thanks..

Comment: Swich Swift version do you use? 2.3?

Comment: Please look up the documentation. `NSURL.fileURLWithPath()` does *not* return an optional. You'll also find some similar questions in the "Related" section.

Answer (score 2):

- `NSURL(string:` returns an optional.
- `NSURL.fileURLWithPath:` does not.

Why not the URL related API in `NSBundle` ??

```
if let targetURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("book", withExtension: "pdf") {
     docController = UIDocumentInteractionController(URL: targetURL)
     ...
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because right side `(NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path))` of the condition is not optional. And in this condition usage of the `if let` is not appropriate.

Comment: so i should remove conditional binding,

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to check creation of `NSURL`, because `fileURL(withPath:)` always returns new instance.

Comment: what shall i do then?

Comment: @Samjhana Remove conditional check

Answer (score 1):

```
 let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("book", ofType: "pdf")
  if(path)
 {
   let targetURL=  URL(fileURLWithPath: path!)
   docController = UIDocumentInteractionController(URL: targetURL)
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Rule of Thumb:

Use `guard let` and `if let` only with **optional types**.

In your case, `let targetURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path)` does not return optional so there is no need to use `if let`, only `let` will do.